# Selection Sort in Cuda

Tags: sorting, cuda

So, I'm trying to implement selection sort in Cuda, but so far I haven't been as successful.

```
__device__ void selection_sort( int *data, int left, int right ){

    for( int i = left ; i <= right ; ++i ){
        int min_val = data[i];
        int min_idx = i;

    // Find the smallest value in the range [left, right].
        for( int j = i+1 ; j <= right ; ++j ){
            int val_j = data[j];
            if( val_j < min_val ){
                min_idx = j;
                min_val = val_j;
            }
        }

        // Swap the values.
        if( i != min_idx ){
            data[min_idx] = data[i];
            data[i] = min_val;
        }
    }
}
```

My main attempt here is to find the minimum and parallelize the solution. Now, I realize the code looks very C++ 'ish but I'm nowhere qualified as skilled in Cuda.

Is there a way to parallelize the solution? Are there any more additions to be made?

Comment: IMHO, I don't think selection sort can be rewritten parallelly. If you need a parallel sort solution, try bubble/merge/bitonic sort.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What you have posted is a device function. Device functions are functions which are run by individual threads and are called from within kernels. By their definition, they are serial operations. So when you say  you "haven't been successfull", what does that mean *axcatly*. And when you say you want to "parallelize the solution", what does that mean *exactly* in the context of this `__device__`function?

Comment: Classic comparison-sort algorithms do not map well to multiprocessor architectures. Parallel sorting is a problem that is still in research, and quite a hard one. You may need to start with simpler stuff first. However, if you are dedicated and want to learn about it no matter what, check e.g. [Sorting Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network), [Cole's parallel merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Parallel_merge_sort), quicksort samples shipped with CUDA toolkit and sorting functions in thrust library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selection sort algorithm for `N` numbers can be roughly described as:

```
for i from N-1 down to 0
    find the maximum element among data[0] ~ data[i]
    swap that maximum element with data[i] within the data array
```

The first part (finding the maximum element) falls into a widely known and well documented class of problems called *reduction*. However, to perform the second part (swapping), you must track the index of the maximum element while comparing the values, and it is not so natural to do that while performing reduction. This is one of the reasons why selection sort do not port well to parallel architectures.

Also, you can see that the problem size diminishes by one for each loop, and this is another aspect of the selection sort algorithm that does not map well to parallel architectures. In case of CUDA, 32 threads form a *warp*, which execute at the same time. Although you can tell arbitrary number of threads to run within a warp, it is generally not recommended to do so because it is a loss of computing power.

I've tried to build a CUDA version of selection sort myself, but I stopped doing it because it seems there are better algorithms well suited for CUDA. But I'll just show you what I've done so far to illustrate why selection sort is not good for CUDA.

Firstly, start from a small and simple problem: sorting 32 elements. Since 32 threads form a warp, you can use [*shuffle* instructions](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-pro-tip-kepler-shuffle/) to find maximum value. ([Full code](https://github.com/nglee/so_answers/blob/master/cuda/170517/kernel.cu))

```
// Finds the maximum element within a warp and gives the maximum element to
// thread with lane id 0. Note that other elements do not get lost but their
// positions are shuffled.
__inline__ __device__ int warpMax(int data, unsigned int threadId)
{
    for (int mask = 16; mask > 0; mask /= 2) {
        int dual_data = __shfl_xor(data, mask, 32);
        if (threadId & mask)
            data = min(data, dual_data);
        else
            data = max(data, dual_data);
    }
    return data;
}

__global__ void selection32(int* d_data, int* d_data_sorted)
{
    unsigned int threadId = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int laneId = threadIdx.x % 32;

    int n = N;
    while(n-- > 0) { 
        // get the maximum element among d_data and put it in d_data_sorted[n]
        int data = d_data[threadId];
        data = warpMax(data, threadId);
        d_data[threadId] = data;

        // now maximum element is in d_data[0]
        if (laneId == 0) {
            d_data_sorted[n] = d_data[0];
            d_data[0] = INT_MIN; // this element is ignored from now on
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    // ... build data and trasfer to d_data ...
    selection32<<<1, 32>>>(d_data, d_data_sorted);
    // ... get the sorted array stored at d_data_sorted ...
}
```

(Some may argue that this is not exactly a selection sort since 1) the array elements of the unsorted area keep shuffling, and 2) it is not an in-place sort. Please note that I'm just trying to show that selection sort does not fit in for CUDA. Also, note that `warpMax` has highly divergent branches, making it less optimal for CUDA.)

The case with only 1 warp of elements may look parallel-ish, but the thing gets worse when the problem size increases to multiple warps. Let's see the case for 1024 elements. (I've chosen the number 1024 becuase it is the maximum number limit of threads in a block.) Now there are 32 warps, and after calling `warpMax` for each warp, we must compare the maximum elements of each warp to get the maximum element among the 1024 elements. This problem of comparing 32 warp-maximum-values cannot be done with `warpMax` because we need to track in which warp the maximum value came from to swap the maximum value with the last element in the data array. One way I can think of for doing this is using one single thread to compare warp-maximum-values. This is not a good implemenation for CUDA becuase other 1023 threads in the block become idle.

Furthermore, if the problem size grows larger than a block can cover, we need to compare the maximum values of each block, implying that we will have to launch separate kernels since we need to synchronize between blocks. And it is redundant to say that we need to keep track of in which block the maximum value came from. All of these just tells that implementing selection sort for CUDA is not a good idea.